# set background image navigation bar

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

So I am try to set a background image for a navigation bar in MonoTouch. The image will be the same everywhere. How would i do this?

In the viewdid load: `NavBar.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromFile ("btn-title-bar.png"));`

doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-title-bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Yep this worked! In c# it would be: gettingStartedBar.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage.FromBundle ("top-bar.png"), UIBarMetrics.Default);

Answer (score 2):

In c# land that is:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage (UIImage.FromFile ("btn-title-bar.png"), UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

Comment: Error CS1501: No overload for method `SetBackgroundImage' takes `1' arguments (CS1501)

Comment: apologies added without checking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code.

```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar@2x.png"];
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put different images on every page then write this method in view did load on every page..

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

and if u want single image on every page then write this code in delegate.m.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]

forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```